# Filtering and Ordering in dimplejs visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

i have visualization with x as userId and y as dates.
for each user i have bubbles that represent some thing with the radius and the color,
because i have some dificullt to show 243 users i added range slider of the users to show maximum 30 users at the time.

examples for lines:

```
    1362499,"Orange Revolution",12.217.127.27,"2004-11-26 01:08:34",62,f;h;m,AR,33.7500,4
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",12.217.127.27,"2004-11-26 02:46:55",3,f,AR,33.7500,4
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",12.217.127.27,"2004-11-26 02:48:16",59,b;m,AR,33.7500,4
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",12.217.127.27,"2004-11-26 02:49:00",11,h,AR,33.7500,4
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",82.82.89.4,"2004-11-26 18:20:14",73,b,AR,73.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",4.5.76.105,"2004-11-26 19:25:02",6,k;m,AR,6.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",193.219.28.144,"2004-11-26 21:18:32",68,c;k;m,AR,68.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",Adamahill,"2004-11-26 22:33:54",4,f,AR,4.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",Andris,"2004-11-27 00:41:39",1,m,AR,1.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",159753,"2004-11-27 13:12:26",89,b;m,AR,89.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",82.160.33.130,"2004-11-27 13:20:15",27,b;c,AR,27.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",213.164.241.16,"2004-11-27 16:34:16",33,b;c,AR,33.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",12.39.93.63,"2004-11-27 18:35:49",43,m,AR,43.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",AlexanderWinston,"2004-11-27 19:42:22",4,f,AR,4.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",130.15.162.58,"2004-11-27 23:27:28",14,c;f,AR,14.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",68.20.24.73,"2004-11-28 05:33:51",1,m,AR,1.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",63.193.101.81,"2004-11-29 03:36:08",135,a;c,AR,207.0000,6
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",167.202.196.72,"2004-11-29 09:40:54",24,b;c,AR,24.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",212.76.39.9,"2004-12-02 17:15:59",13,c;m,AR,13.0000,1
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",63.193.101.81,"2004-12-02 19:03:06",256,a;c;g,AR,207.0000,6
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",63.193.101.81,"2004-12-02 19:03:35",1,f,AR,207.0000,6
   1362499,"Orange Revolution",63.193.101.81,"2004-12-03 03:43:01",589,a;c;m,AR,207.0000,6
```

### My questions is:

1. can i filter the data by range of users? kind od indexing 1-30, 200-230 etc.
2. can i order in other order rules except for the X axis( userId)? for example, the number of bubbles for each user, the AVG of radiuses of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter but that would be separate from dimple, just reduce the dataset that you pass to the chart.

You can set extra order rules using the [addOrderRule method](http://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#addOrderRule) of the axis.

NB. Version 2.0.0 has a bug in it's ordering logic which might make it difficult, I suggest you either get [version 1.1.5](http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.5.min.js) or if you want some features from version 2 you can pick up the [current pre-release build](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/dist/dimple.v2.0.2.min.js) from Git Hub which has a fix in place.

Comment: for the range issue i'll do this separately. but the build version 2.0.2 solve what? i tried use this addOrderRule but it didnt fit to order by some bubble count

Comment: another problem is that i use vis like [link](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_price_range_lollipop) and i cant color the charts in same color and the opacity didnt change

Comment: It fixed a bug with ordering by function or single dimenesion, you can create predicate functions to deal with custom behaviours.  I suggest you create a separate question for your problem with colour and opacity and include a jsfiddle of what you have so far, then it should be quite easy to see what you are doing wrong.